# I'm looking to create a function to increment value of a data selector in ACF loop

Tags: php, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a WP site with ACF (flexible content) and AOS.js

I'm trying to have the data-as-delay increment with each element added to the page.

I have tried wrapping everything in a `<ul><li>` but then I'd have to change all my CSS to accommodate. Since I'm trying to learn, I figured I'd try to create a function. But I don't know where to start.

```
<?php while ( have_rows('panneau') ) : the_row(); ?>
  <div class="col" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="200">
    <?php $image = get_sub_field('image'); if( !empty($image) ): ?>
      <img src="<?= $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?= $image['alt']; ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

So I'd like every new img to have 200ms more delay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple incremator in your loop should do the trick.

```
<?php $i = 200; ?>

<?php while ( have_rows('panneau') ) : the_row(); ?>
  <div class="col" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <?php $image = get_sub_field('image'); if( !empty($image) ): ?>
      <img src="<?= $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?= $image['alt']; ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

<?php $i = $i + 200;?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, it did the trick. I'll try and remember that!